# Make modal push segue programmatically — Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a button, which when is pressed, adds a new subview with other buttons on it. I have done like this.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget: @selector(newView)];


- (void)newView
{
    UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectmake(0,0,100,100)];
    [self.view addSubview:newView];
}
```

Now when the button is pressed the new view is just added. I want to animate the new view like I can do in the IB, with push segue modal style. How can I do that programmatically?

Comment: So you dont want to add UIViewController but u want to add UIView but It should animate like we present UIViewControlle. Am I understand right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
- (void)newView
{

     [self.view addSubview:newView]
      newView.frame = // somewhere offscreen, in the direction you want it to appear    from
      [UIView animateWithDuration:10.0 
                 animations:^{
                     newView.frame = // its final location
      }];

}
```

Comment: how do I animate the creation of the new view? I can't put the whole UIView *newView = ... inside the animation right?

Comment: no, you create your on the button click and then pass the view and set  it's frame properties, to animate. I hope it make sense.

Comment: thank you I made it work! But it takes like 0.5-1 sec before it animates. I´ve tried with [UIView setAnimateionDelay:0.0]; but it doesn't make any difference

Comment: sure but do you know a way to solve the problem I wront in my previous comment?

Comment: I can't say much unless I debug what you have written, however, you might want to check this article

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW1

Comment: Hopefully, you might find some answer in there.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with `performSegueWithIdentifier`, here is the code

```
- (void)newView
{
    //execute segue programmatically
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"MySegue" sender: self];
}
```

Comment: but how do I change the type of push segue? like push or modal?

Comment: One way is to change the seque type in storyboard where you define the segue. Under identifier "style".

Comment: Really helpful! Everything I tried was way too complicated this simplifies things!

Answer (score 0):

You can present a new viewcontroller like this:

```
- (void)newView
{
     //Embed your new View into a plain UIViewController
     UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectmake(0,0,100,100)];
     UIViewController *yourNewViewController= [[UIViewController alloc] init];
     controller.view = newView;

    //Present it animated         
    [self presentViewController:yourNewViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: the view was loaded but then it just turned black:(

Comment: How do you create the view? In my example code i didnt put anything in it (just the initwithframe), you have to init with something more inside

Comment: Did you mean yourNewViewController.view = newView  instead of controller.view = newView ?